# R: Use terra to rescale large raster files and run in parallel

Tags: r, parallel-processing, terra, clamp

I have some very large raster files and want to rescale the values of these rasters to 0-1.
Here are the information of my large rasters:

```
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 161239, 132862, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 25, 25  (x, y)
extent      : 2634975, 5956525, 1385025, 5416000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs 
source      : mean_temp.tif 
name        : mean 
min value   : -9.1 
max value   : 15.4
```

To rescale the raster values to 0~1, I separate the raster values to three parts:

- For pixels with values <= 5th quantile, all of these pixels get
  values 0.
- Pixel values that are greater or equal to 95% will get 1.
- Pixel values between the 5th quantile and 95th quantile with be
  normalized to 0~1.

I use `terra` and `sf` R packages for rescaling and make smaller tiles of the large raster.

Here is how I do it:

```
library(terra)
library(sf)

min_offset <- rast("test.tif")

quantiles_min <- spatSample(min_offset, 10^4, "regular")
q2 <- as.data.frame(quantile(quantiles_min, probs=c(0.05, 0.95), na.rm=TRUE))
print(q2)
#Read in data in sf format.
c_shape <- read_sf("test.shp") 

# create an initial grid for centroid determination
c_grid <- st_make_grid(c_shape, cellsize = c(5e5, 5e5), square = TRUE) |>
  st_as_sf()

c_grid_spat <- vect(c_grid)
## make tiles of large rasters:
filename <- paste0("/tile/tile", "_.tif")
tile <- makeTiles(min_offset,c_grid_spat, filename, overwrite = TRUE)
tile_rasters <- c(lapply(tile, rast))

Rescaling <- function(x){
  ##clamp to get the range of values that are need to be rescaled.
  middle_min <- clamp(x,q2[1,1], q2[2,1], values = FALSE)
  
  #use normalization to rescale the middle range values.
  normalized_mid <- ((middle_min-q2[1,1])/(q2[2,1]- q2[1,1]))|> round(digits = 1)
  
  
  ## Values that are lower or equal to 5th quantile became 0
  min_q5 <- clamp(x, upper = q2[1,1], value=FALSE)|> round(digits = 1)
  
  min_repl5 <- init(min_q5, fun=0) |> mask(min_q5)
  
  ##values that are greater or equal to 95% get  1.
  min_q95 <- clamp(x,q2[2,1],Inf, value = FALSE)|> round(digits = 1)
  min_repl95 <- init(min_q95, fun=1) |> mask(min_q95)
  
  ##save raster
  final_min<- merge(normalized_mid,min_repl5,min_repl95)
  return(final_min)
}

x <- rast(tile_rasters[2]);Rescaling(x) #this works


MIs <- function(w){
  r <- rast(w)
  y <- Rescaling(r)
  wrap(y,proxy=TRUE)
} #This function work. when > i=1;  r <- tile_rasters[i] ;MI_tile <- MIs(r)

###Test function###
test <- MIs(tile_rasters[2])#this work with next line.
test <- terra::unwrap(test)#this work
```

When I tried to apply the two functions above in `foreach` parallel, I encountered some errors:

```
library(parallelly)
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)

cl <- makeClusterPSOCK(length(tile_rasters), autoStop = TRUE)
registerDoParallel(cl)

 test <- foreach(x =1:length(tile_rasters),
                 .packages = "terra") %dopar% {
                   resu <- MIs(tile_rasters[i])
                   return(resu)
                 }
stopCluster(cl)
```

Error message:

```
Error in { : task 1 failed - "NULL value passed as symbol address"
```

Does anyone has clues that how I can solve this problem to have my function parallelized on each raster tile?

For the test.shp file, you can find it from [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1SyxA4lBiGNH5vgl_CGeo7K6UNe6jqhVM?usp=sharing), for the test.tif file, download from [here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WNvU9L52nnX4XuVZPcQmKyHjcwmBmE0s/view?usp=sharing)

To merge all the tile results into a final raster, I use `vrt` function, but it seems to still take quite some memory space.
Here is how I did it:

```
t.lst <- list.files("/AllTiles/", pattern=".tif", full.names=TRUE)
MIs_final <- function(t.lst, fout="") {
  r <- vrt(t.lst)
  if (fout != "") {
    writeRaster(r, fout, overwrite=TRUE)
    fout
  } else {
    wrap(r)
  }
}
```

Comment: You're probably running into the issue with non-exportable objects. For a possible workaround, see https://future.futureverse.org/articles/future-4-non-exportable-objects.html#package-terra

Comment: @HenrikB Thanks for your replies. Indeed, the 'SpatRast' can not be used in parallel, but my input data is still in 'Spatrast' format. I finally solved my problems by using the solution provided by Robert. Instead of running in parallel, I run my rescaling by using small tiles and merging them by ```vrt``` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrap the SpatRaster that is send back from a node, but you also need to wrap the input SpatRaster. But I would send the filenames instead. Otherwise you would probably run out of memory.

Something like this

Set up

```
library(terra)
f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
r <- rast(f)
qnt <- global(r, quantile, probs=c(0.05, 0.95), na.rm=TRUE, maxcell=10^4) |> unlist()
qrng <- diff(qnt)
tiles <- makeTiles(r, 20, overwrite = TRUE)
```

A function that takes the file (this function should be much faster than yours; perhaps reducing the benefit of parallelization)

```
rescaler1 <- function(f){
    x <- rast(f)
    norm <- (x-qnt[1])/qrng
    rcl <- rbind(c(-Inf, qnt[1], 0), c(qnt[2], Inf, 1))
    cls <- classify(x, rcl, other=NA)
    cover(cls, norm) |> round(1)
}
```

or easier to understand (but probably slower)

```
rescaler2 <- function(f) {
    x <- rast(f)
    x <- ifel(x < qnt[1], 0,  
            ifel(x > qnt[2], 1, (x-qnt[1]) / qrng))
    round(x, 1)
}
```

And now you can do

```
a <- rescaler1(tiles[2])
b <- rescaler2(tiles[2])
```

And a function like this

```
MIs <- function(f, fout="") {
    r <- rescaler1(f)
    if (fout != "") {
        writeRaster(r, fout, overwrite=TRUE)
        fout
    } else {
        wrap(r)
    }
}
```

And you need to export `qnt` and `qrng` to the nodes

Here is an alternative approach with multiple cores

```
fresc <- function(x){
    x <- ifelse(x < qnt[1], 0,  
            ifelse(x > qnt[2], 1, (x-qnt[1]) / qrng))
    round(x, 1)
}

r <- rast(f)
a  <- app(r, fresc)

library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(4)
clusterExport(cl, c("qnt", "qrng"))
b <- app(r, fresc, cores=cl)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! It helped a lot! @RobertHijmans . I was wondering does  ```a  <- app(r, fresc)```  also process the ```fresc``` function in parallel? When I test the ```a  <- app(r, fresc)``` and ```b <- app(r, fresc, cores=cl)```, I found the ```a  <- app(r, fresc)``` actually run faster for my data. Another thing that I tried is to modify the ```MIs``` function to ```MIs_final``` for merging all the tiles to a final one by using ```vrt```, and I found this could also save some memory instead of just doing ```vrt``` itself. I added the function I created in my post.

Comment: The first one is sequential. But the overhead of using parallelization is probably too large to make it count with a simple function like this.